# Extraction of features from rviz map

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In my project, I am required to evaluate accuracy of rviz map generated using GMapping algorithm on a robotino. I need to develop a repeatable method to extract features (not the 'measure' tool in rviz) and determine the distance between them on the map and compare it to measured real-world distances. How do I go about extracting the features from an rviz map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201932/extraction-of-features-from-rviz-map/) by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can interpret the map as an image and do standard image processing on it, for example using OpenCV. This way, you can run different feature detectors/descriptors on the map and use those. An example of doing exactly that is provided in the [mapstitch](http://wiki.ros.org/mapstitch) package that allows aligning maps which each other. The code for converting a map to a cv:Mat is [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch/blob/master/src/rosmain.cpp#L54).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on 2015-01-28**:
Thank you. So I take the stored rviz map and run the code (that converts to a cv:Mat), this will give me an image, then I run image processing algorithms using OpenCV, have I understood it right? What is the usage of the mapstitch package?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-01-31**:
The mapstitch package performs feature detection on two (different) maps. estimates the relative transform between them and generates a stitched/fused map from both.

**Comment by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on 2015-02-04**:
Thanks. I will try it out.